# создать из строки вложенный объект

Tags: javascript

есть строка:

```
var q = 'user.name.firstname=Bob&user.name.lastname=Smith&user.favoritecolor=Light%20Blue'
```

нужно из нее сделать такой объект

```
{
  'user': {
    'name': {
      'firstname': 'Bob',
      'lastname': 'Smith'
     },
    'favoritecolor': 'Light Blue'
   }
}
```

застрял на добавлении вложенных объектов, вот пример моего кода

```
function convertQueryToMap(query) {
var tmp = {};
query = query.replace(/\./ig, ':');
query = query.replace(/\=/ig, ':');
query = query.replace(/\%20/ig, ' ');
var arr = query.split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var elem = arr[i].split(':');
    for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++){
        if(tmp[elem[j]] == undefined){
            tmp[elem[j]] = {};
        }
    }
}

return tmp;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var q = 'user.name.firstname=Bob&user.name.lastname=Smith&user.favoritecolor=Light%20Blue';

/*{
  'user': {
    'name': {
      'firstname': 'Bob',
      'lastname': 'Smith'
     },
    'favoritecolor': 'Light Blue'
   }
}*/

function convertQueryToMap(query) {
  var tmp = {}, tmp1;
  query = query.replace(/\./ig, ':');
  query = query.replace(/\=/ig, ':');
  query = query.replace(/\%20/ig, ' ');
  var arr = query.split('&');

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var elem = arr[i].split(':');
    tmp1 = tmp;
    for (var j = 0; j < elem.length - 2; j++){
        if(tmp1[elem[j]] == undefined){
            tmp1[elem[j]] = {};
        }
        tmp1 = tmp1[elem[j]];
    }
    tmp1[elem[j]] = elem[j+1];
  }

  return tmp;
}

var res = convertQueryToMap(q);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: спасибо! час не мог догнать...

Comment: `.replace(/\%20/ig, ' ')` - это шедеврально!

Comment: @Other рад, что Вам понравилось

Comment: Жду вторую часть, где будет: `.replace(/\%20/ig, ' ').replace(/\%0A/ig, "\n")...` :)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуемся передачей по ссылке:

```js
let q    = 'user.name.firstname=Bob&user.name.lastname=Smith&user.favoritecolor=Light%20Blue',
    data = {};

// Каждую запись "Ключ=Значение"
q.split('&').forEach(part => {
  let [path, value] = part.split('='); // Ключ и значение
  
  let pointer = data; // Указываем на корень объекта
  path.split('.').forEach((part, i, arr) => { // Делим по точке (кусочки пути)
    // Если очередной части пути ещё не находится в базе
    if(!pointer[part])
      // То добавляем либо новый объект, либо значение, если это последняя часть
      pointer[part] = i === arr.length - 1 ? decodeURIComponent(value) : {};
    
    // Смещаем указатель на новый объект. Или на значение, но это не важно тогда
    pointer = pointer[part];
  });
});

console.info(data);
```

Comment: decodeURIComponent вроде для обеи частей должно применяться, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy, может быть. Правда я не считаю это нужным, ключи - особая вещь.

Comment: Я вот тоже ответ смастерил :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = 'user.name.firstname=Bob&user.name.lastname=Smith&user.favoritecolor=Light%20Blue';

var res = {};

s.replace(/([^=&]+|(?==))(=?)([^&]*)/g, function (m, key, eq, val) {
  var path = decodeURIComponent(key).split(".");
  key = path.pop();
  val = eq ? decodeURIComponent(val) : true;
  
  var obj = res;

  for (var q=0; q<path.length; ++q) {
    obj = obj[path[q]] = obj[path[q]] || {};
  }

  obj[key] = val;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Поздравляю :) Ох, чую я что в этом парсере не нужны регулярки...

Comment: @Other, почему не нужны? Так меньше кода писать, чем два вложенных сплита :)

Comment: Ладно, ладно, возможно это, поэтому и плюсанул. Но я считаю что лучше просесть на лишнюю мс., чем писать код, в который нужно долго вникать. По регулярке фиг поймёшь что и зачем без вдумчивого анализа.

Comment: Кстати, может по гольфу? :) Не лучший вариант, но на безгольфье и это - гольф.

Comment: @Other, вообще-то я подозреваю, что регулярка работает медленнее, чем 2 сплита. На мой взгляд, этот код проще :) А гольф - ну можно - там есть чего нагородить)) Давай Николаса позовём, у него мысли были)